# Could not find any resource in visual studio 2010 Professional

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, resources

I'm trying to use resources in visual basic project. It is always giving `Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture`.

Testing: I added one Vb form into solution explored and later I added one picture box in to that form and later I added that resource file. After I ran that project...I get resource could not find.

I used same project in other system. That is working fine. ( I am not sure any files are missing in visual studio )

If I do in c# ..that is working on my system.

can any one tell me is it need to repair or install visual studio

Comment: If you right-click the resource, and choose Properties, is the buildtype "Embedded Resource"? If not then change it.

Comment: I already set to "Embedded Resource". Even though it is sohwing could not find resource error.

Comment: Use `ildasm` to find the exact resource name.  It's usually built from the namespace and folder the resource is in.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can we use ildasam in project to find resource name(while running project).